# Sticky header and footer scrollable main area

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

I want my page to have a fixed `header` and `footer`, which must stay on screen all the time. The lateral panel is on an `aside`, and the main content inside a `section`.

Using JavaScript, I managed to keep the `aside` occupying all the remaining height (window.height - header.height - footer.height). But it only works when the `section` is not too high. When I resize the window, I can see that the `footer` is disappearing under the bottom edge of the window, giving room to the `section`.

I tried many different combinations of overflow-y (inside `section`, on the `div` inside it, on both), to no avail. How can I solve it?

I made a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/awqj0s8h/).

```js
function resize() {
  var hPage = window.innerHeight;
  var hHead = document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight;
  var hFoot = document.getElementById('footer').offsetHeight;
  document.getElementById('spn').innerHTML = 'Page: ' + hPage + '<BR>Head: ' + hHead + '<BR>Foot: ' + hFoot;
  document.getElementById('aside').style.height = (hPage - hHead - hFoot) + 'px';
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
header {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
}
section {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
section div {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
aside {
  float: left;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 20%;
}
aside p {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
footer {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body onload='resize()' onresize='resize()'>
  <header id='header'>Test 0.1</header>
  <aside id='aside'>
    <p>Menu 1</p>
    <p>Menu 2</p>
    <p>Menu 3</p>
    <p>Menu 4</p>
    <p><span id='spn'>n</span>
    </p>
  </aside>
  <section>
    <div id='divMain'>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Col1</th>
          <th>Col2</th>
          <th>Col3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer id='footer'>Address,
    <br>phone,
    <br>etc.
    <br>
    <br>Address,
    <br>phone,
    <br>etc.</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the flexbox approach, no javascript is needed. Added a `<main>` element wraps the `<aside>` and `<section>`.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9djyswr5/)**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
}
main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 0;
}
aside {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 20%;
  overflow: auto;
}
aside p {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
section {
  width: 80%;
  overflow: auto;
}
section div {
  padding: 10px;
}
footer {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header id='header'>
  Test 0.1
</header>
<main>
  <aside id='aside'>
    <p>Menu 1</p>
    <p>Menu 2</p>
    <p>Menu 3</p>
    <p>Menu 4</p>
    <p><span id='spn'>n</span>
    </p>
  </aside>
  <section>
    <div id='divMain'>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Col1</th>
          <th>Col2</th>
          <th>Col3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
<footer id='footer'>
  Address,
  <br>phone,
  <br>etc.
  <br>
  <br>Address,
  <br>phone,
  <br>etc.
  <br>
</footer>
```

Comment: Your example don't work here nor in jsfiddle. The footer is disappearing. The scrollbar should be inside the section/main div, not on the whole page.

Comment: @Rodrigo I just fixed that so it should work fine on Firefox too. Let me know.

Comment: Great, Pangloss! Now it worked like a charm! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `position:fixed` to the footer & also to show the table if it's height overflows , you need to add scroll option.

Here is a css which may help you

```
#footer{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
width:100%
}
#divMain{
overflow-y:auto;  // scrollbar will only appear when require
height:500px; // you can adjust this height
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/awqj0s8h/1/)

Comment: In your example, the scroll bar appears, but hides partially behind the footer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the `header` and `footer` to have a fixed position then you should use `position:fixed` attribute.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tomjerry25/94rbu87z/1/)